# картинки в sitemap для яндекса

Tags: seo

Как быть со следующей ошибкой в `sitemap`?

> Неизвестный тег Строка 1: image:image

Как быть с  изображениями в Яндексе? Будет ли эта ошибка влиять на позиции и ранжирование сайта?

Comment: А пофиксить ошибку генерации можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Яндекс не поддерживает тег image:image.

На ранжирование в Яндексе не влияет, потому что Яндекс на всех сайтах одинаково этот тег не поддерживает.